# Where did I make mistakes?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation

I want to solve the following problem:

$\Delta_ u = u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0 \hspace{0.5cm} 0<x<\pi, \hspace{0.2cm} 0<y<1$
$u(x,0) = T_0 \cos x$
$u(x,1) = T_0 \cos^2 x$
$u_{x}(0,y)=u_{x}(\pi,y) = 0$

**My attempt**

Let $u(x,y) = X(x)Y(y) \neq 0$. $\hspace{0.2cm}$Applying to $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0 $ we obtain the two ODE
$X'' + \lambda X=0$
$Y'' - \lambda Y =0$
where $\lambda$ is a constant.
Due to the problem conditions we have
$u_{x}(0,y) = X'(0)Y(y) = 0 \Rightarrow X'(0) = 0$
$u_{x}(\pi,y) = X'(\pi)Y(y) = 0 \Rightarrow X'(\pi) = 0$
We then mount the problem
\begin{cases}
X'' + \lambda X = 0\\
X'(0) = X'(\pi) = 0
\end{cases}

We know that for $\lambda> 0$, let's say $\lambda = k^2$ with $ k \neq 0 $, we have
$X(x) = a \cos(kx) + b \sin(kx)$ $\Rightarrow X'(x) = -ka\sin(kx) + kb\cos(kx)$
So $X'(0) = kb \Rightarrow b=0 $
Therefore $X(x) = a \cos(kx)$
furthermore $X'(\pi) = 0 \Rightarrow \sin(k \pi ) = 0 \Rightarrow k \pi = n \pi \Rightarrow \lambda_{n} = n^2$, $\hspace{0.4cm} n \geq 0 \hspace{0.4cm}$ Is it possible that $n = 0$? 
Therefore $X_{n}(x) = \cos(nx)$
I think that $ n \geq 0 $ instead of $ n \geq 1 $ because I can see that if $ \lambda = 0 $, then $ X_{0} = 1 $, and can I assume $ Y_{0} = a_{0}/2 $? 
I dare not affirm that.
On the other hand, from the ODE $Y'' - \lambda Y = 0$ we obtain
$Y_{n}(y) = a_{n}\cosh(ny) + b_{n}\sinh(ny)$
$$\therefore u(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{[a_{n}\cosh(ny) + b_{n}\sinh(ny)]\cos(nx)}$$
From this I get that
$$a_{n} = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}{T_{0}\cos(x)\cos(nx)}dx = 0$$
$$b_{n} = \frac{2}{\pi \sinh(n)}\int_{0}^{\pi}{T_{0}\cos^2(x)\cos(nx)}dx = 0$$
Clearly this would give the trivial solution $u(x,y) =0$, which is not possible.
Where did I make mistakes?

Answer (score 1):

The terma $a_1$ and $b_2$ are not zero because

$a_1 = \frac{2T_0}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \cos^2(x)\, dx \ne 0$

$b_2  = \frac{2}{\pi \sinh(2)}\int_{0}^{\pi}{T_{0}\cos^2(x)\cos(2x)}dx  
 = \frac{2}{\pi \sinh(2)}\int_{0}^{\pi}{T_{0}\frac{1 + \cos 2x}{2}  \cos(2x)}dx \ne 0
$

Comment: $a_ {n} \neq 0$ only when $n = 1$ and $b_ {n} \neq 0$ only when $n = 2$? I'm right?

Comment: @Curious Yes, you are right.